# Error running Powershell Script in SQL Server Agent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent, jobs, powershell

I have a SQL job that runs via SQL Server Agent (Running SQL Server 2012 Enterprise). The last step of the job is to run an application located on a network share. Unfortunately I don't know the name of the folder that the application is in (the folder is the version number), so I'm using PowerShell to find it:

```
set-location "\\server\companydocuments\MyApp\Application Files\"
$name = Get-ChildItem | sort name -desc | select -f 1 | select name
cd $name.name
& ".\Application.exe"
```

If I open a PowerShell window on the SQL Server then it works fine. When I run this in SQL Server Agent I get the following error:

```
A job step received an error at line 1 in a PowerShell script.
The corresponding line is 'set-location "\\server\companydocuments\MyApp\Application Files\'"
```

I thought it might be a permissions issue so I've tried SQL Server Agent running under my credentials (it's a test server, not production) but I still get the same error. I've also tried mapping a network drive to the shared folder instead of UNC paths, but the same error.

Can anyone suggest how I can connect to this folder?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe your issue is going to be the `SQLPS` provider. Since PowerShell steps in SQL Server Agent automatically put you into the context of that provider some commands that work in your normal console will not function the same way. A write up was done [here](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2012/11/05/pstip-using-unc-paths-when-working-with-powershell-providers/) with `Set-Location`. You basically have to tell `SQLPS` the provider you want to use.

Your code would look something like below:

```
set-location -Path Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::"\\server\companydocuments\MyApp\Application Files\"
```

You could also wrap the remainder into two lines if you wanted to:

```
cd (Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object name -Descending | Select name -First 1).name
& ".\Application.exe"
```

Comment: @ShawnMelton what about running powershell commands on a remote server? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83068/run-a-powershell-script-on-a-different-server-from-inside-a-sql-server-job

Comment: We have had this same issue and found doing a `cd c:` at the beginning of the script sorted the context/location issue. Then all UNC paths worked as expected.

Comment: `cd c:` is an alias to using `Set-Location C:`, so it is the same command.

Answer (score 2):

The other alternative would be to use operating system command and give powershell.exe c:/path/script.ps1 as command and save your script in script.ps1. This will ensure using OS powershell instead of using provider.