# SQL Server Job Powershell is failing

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a **SQL Server 2014** instance job that runs nightly that moves backups from the local drive to a network drive. I wrote it using PowerShell.

```
$mypath = $('F:\Backup\CRMDB01$CRMDB012014\Prod\Full\')
$mydestination = '\\stagingshare\fromprod\'
$myfile = gci $mypath | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1
copy-item -path ($mypath + $myfile) -destination $mydestination
```

The job is failing with "reason: line(1): Syntax Error". I have it set to "Run as:" proxy_1.

proxy_1 has a credentialed name next to it that has access to the share. I don't have any principals selected.

What am I missing?

Comment: Take the `$()` out from around your first line, so should just be `$myPath = 'F:\Backup\CRMDB01$CRMDB012014\Prod\Full\'`

Comment: That was it. It now works, but for some reason doesn't copy the file.

Comment: Try adding a line that just calls c:\.  I've found that the default provider is SQL when running PowerShell jobs from SQL Agent.  I typically throw a line that calls just C:\, to force the provider to switch to the file system.  It's the least fragile method I've found for doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax error you are getting is from the `$()` this is taken as a token in SQL Server Agent context...so it will always bark at that; removing it should fix the syntax error.

On the copy issue you will likely need to specify the property you want to pass into `Copy-Item`. Just passing `$myfile` is not going to work because that contains the full object of the output from `gci`. So change it to something like:

```
$myfile = gci $mypath | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 -ExpandPropety FullName
Copy-Item -path $myfile -destination $mydestination
```

Now `$myFile` will contain the full path to your last file:
[image]

Comment: This is awesome. It succeeds now in the SQL job, but still doesn't move the file. Thoughts?

Comment: Is there a file to move? Permissions? There are a handful of things to check on why the file is not going anywhere.

Comment: Yes the file exists. The proxy that it's using is linked to a windows user that has full writes to the share. Is there any where to look to see logs for a successful job?

Comment: Add an output file to the SQL Agent job will capture anything output by the script.

Comment: The job script encountered the following errors. These errors did not stop the script:
A job step received an error at line 4 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is 'copy-item -path $myfile -destination $mydestination'. Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'Source and destination path did not resolve to the same provider.'

Is this something that I need specify with the paths?

Comment: So I added this to the front of the network share: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::

And am now getting an access is denied to the path. How should the credentials be setup for this? proxy_1 is mapped to a user account that has access to the path.

Comment: Ah, yeah I brought up using that in [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/51885/507). The permissions for that proxy will need full permissions to the destination (both the share and folder itself), or the source based on what your error shows.

Comment: Ah ha! The user account didn't have access to the share, just the folder. It now works, beautifully. Thanks!

Comment: So for some reason this executes every night, but it doesn't actually move the file. The output file is blank, so I told it to log everything to the history. No errors are thrown there. If I start the job at the file moving step it works fine. Thoughts?